# Making a conditional app.use() with Node and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I would like to be able to set an app.use() path depending on the domain my Node.JS server receives the request as to return one set of files or another. I have tried with the following code, but when testing the files are never returned to the client.

```js
app.use('/scripts', (req, res) => {

    if (req.host == `mysite.com`) {

        express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'landing', 'frontend/scripts'));
        
    } else if (req.host == `admin.mysite.com`) {

        express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'admin', 'frontend/scripts'));
    }
});
```

I am using express as a dependancy to try and do this, but no avail, I am willing to try other packages if this can help solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but I would assume you can keep a reference to each static route and then just forward the requests, don't forget next so that normal 404 can be handled.

eg.

```
const static1 = express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'landing', 'frontend/scripts'));
const static2 = express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'admin', 'frontend/scripts'));

app.use('/scripts', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.hostname == `mysite.com`) {
        static1(req, res, next);       
    } else if (req.hostname == `admin.mysite.com`) {
        static2(req, res, next);
    } else res.end(`host: ${req.hostname} not found`);
});
```

Comment: Just tested this, but no luck, I get the same problem, the routes never resolve, and the site is just stuck loading

Comment: @ChristianSmithMantas  works for me, I've a feeling your host is wrong, ps:  req.host is deprecated so I would avoid that.  I'll update my answer to handle invalid hosts.

Comment: This did indeed solve the issue, you where right, the issue was with the hostname syntax whit I had wrong, thank you!